# Counting Nodes in a Binary Tree

Tags: c++, function, templates, binary-tree

http://pastebin.com/gGY6Dw5y

There is a link to the code above. The point is to make a method to count the nodes in a binary tree, then create two methods that also count the nodes, one for each side of the tree. My question is how to call the method to count the nodes.

My question is how do I call my countNodes method. I don't know what kind of argument it's looking for.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
template <class datatype>
class treenode{
public:
    datatype data;
    string qa;
    treenode<datatype> *lchild, *rchild;

};
template<class datatype>
class btree{
private:
    treenode<datatype> *root, *current;
public:
    btree();
    bool tree_empty(void);
    void insertdata(datatype x); //call from main program to insert data
    void inserttree(treenode<datatype> *&p, datatype d);
    void inorder(treenode<datatype> *p);
    void printinorder(void);//call from main program
    void preorder(treenode<datatype> *p);
    void printpreorder(void);//call from main program
    void postorder(treenode<datatype> *p);
    void printpostorder(void);//call from main program
    void deletevalue(datatype v);
    void deltree(datatype val, treenode<datatype> *&p);
    treenode<datatype>* findmin(treenode<datatype> *p);
    void inserttree2(treenode<datatype> *&p, datatype d, string qas);
    void insertdata2(datatype x, string a);
    void yesno(void);
    int countNodes(treenode<datatype> *p);


};

template<class datatype>
btree<datatype>::btree(){
    root =NULL;
};

template<class datatype>
bool btree<datatype>::tree_empty(){
    bool x = true;
    if(root == NULL){
            x = true;
    }else{
            x = false;
    }
    return x;
};

template<class datatype>
void btree<datatype>::insertdata(datatype x){
    inserttree(root,x);
};

template<class datatype>
void btree<datatype>::inserttree(treenode<datatype> *&p, datatype d){
    if(p == NULL){
            p = new treenode<datatype>;
            p->data = d;
            p->lchild = NULL;
            p->rchild = NULL;
    }else{
            if(p->data > d)
                    inserttree(p->lchild,d);
            else
                    inserttree(p->rchild,d);
    }
};

template<class datatype>
void btree<datatype>::inorder(treenode<datatype> *p){
    if(p!= NULL){
            inorder(p->lchild);
            cout<< p->data << "  ";
            inorder(p->rchild);
    }
};

template<class datatype>
void btree<datatype>::printinorder(void){
    inorder(root);
};

template<class datatype>
void btree<datatype>::preorder(treenode<datatype> *p){
    if(p!= NULL){
            cout<< p->data << "  ";
            preorder(p->lchild);
            preorder(p->rchild);
    }
};

template<class datatype>
void btree<datatype>::printpreorder(void){
    preorder(root);
};

template<class datatype>
void btree<datatype>::postorder(treenode<datatype> *p){
    if(p!= NULL){
            postorder(p->lchild);
            postorder(p->rchild);
            cout<< p->data << "  ";
    }
};

template<class datatype>
void btree<datatype>::printpostorder(void){
    postorder(root);
};

template<class datatype>
void btree<datatype>::deletevalue(datatype v){
    deltree(v,root);
};

template<class datatype>
void btree<datatype>::deltree(datatype val, treenode<datatype> *&p){
    treenode<datatype> *buff;
    if(p != NULL)
            if(val < p->data)
                    deltree(val,p->lchild);
            else
                    if(val > p->data)
                            deltree(val, p->rchild);
                    else
                            if(p->lchild == NULL && p->rchild == NULL)
                                    p= NULL;
                            else
                                    if(p->lchild == NULL)
                                            p= p->rchild;
                                    else
                                            if(p->rchild == NULL)
                                                    p = p->lchild;
                                            else
                                            {
                                                    buff = findmin(p->rchild);
                                                    buff->lchild = p->lchild;
                                                    p = p->rchild;

                                            }


};
template<class datatype>
void btree<datatype>::inserttree2(treenode<datatype> *&p, datatype d, string qas){
    if(p ==NULL){
            p = new treenode<datatype>;
            p->data = d;
            p->qa = qas;
            p->lchild = NULL;
            p->rchild = NULL;
    }else{
            if(p->data > d)
                    inserttree2(p->lchild,d,qas);
            else
                    inserttree2(p->rchild,d,qas);
    }
};

template<class datatype>
void btree<datatype>::insertdata2(datatype x, string a){
    inserttree2(root,x,a);
};
template<class datatype>
void btree<datatype>::yesno(void){
    current = root;
    bool solved = false;
    char c;
    cout<<current->qa<<endl;
    while(!solved){
            cout<<"Enter a Y or N";
            cin>> c;
            if(c == 'Y' ||c == 'N'){
            if(c == 'Y'){
                    current = current->lchild;
            }
            if(c == 'N'){
                    current = current->rchild;
            }
            cout<<current->qa<<endl;
            if(current->lchild == NULL){
                    solved = true;
                    cout<<"You have your answer "<<endl;
            }
            }
            }
};

template<class datatype>
treenode<datatype>* btree<datatype>::findmin(treenode<datatype> *p){
    if(p->lchild == NULL)
            return (p);
    else
            return(findmin(p->lchild));
};

template<class datatype>
int btree<datatype>::countNodes(treenode<datatype> *p){
int count = 1;    
    if ( p == NULL ){
       return 0;  
            }else{
       int count = 1;   /
       count += countNodes(p->lchild);  

       count += countNodes(p->rchild);
            }                                  /
       return count;  
    };

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


    btree<int> genesistree;
    int datavalues,
            deletevalues,
            addvalues,
            newdata,
            olddata,
            newnewdata,
            ifstatement,
            c,
    *p;
    bool flag;
    genesistree.insertdata(14);
            genesistree.insertdata(2);
            genesistree.insertdata(34);
            genesistree.insertdata(41);
            genesistree.insertdata(12);


    /*
    if(genesistree.tree_empty()){
            cout<<"The list is empty"<<endl;
    }else{
            cout<<"The list is not empty"<<endl;
    }
    cout<<""<<endl;

    cout<<"Enter the ammount of data values for the tree"<<endl;
    cin>>datavalues;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    for(c = datavalues, c >= 0; c--;){
            cout<<"Enter a datavalue for the tree"<<endl;
            cin>>newdata;
            genesistree.insertdata(newdata);
            cout<<""<<endl;
    }

    cout<<""<<endl;

    if(genesistree.tree_empty()){
            cout<<"The list is empty"<<endl;
    }else{
            cout<<"The list is not empty"<<endl;
    }

    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Print Preorder"<<endl;
    genesistree.printpreorder();
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Print in order"<<endl;
    genesistree.printinorder();
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Print Postorder"<<endl;
    genesistree.printpostorder();
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter the ammount of datavalues you would like to delete"<<endl;
    cin>>deletevalues;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    if(deletevalues < datavalues){
    for(c = deletevalues, c >= 0; c--;){
            cout<<"Enter a datavalue to delete in the tree"<<endl;
            cin>>olddata;
            genesistree.deletevalue(olddata);

    }
    }else{
            if(deletevalues == 0){
                    cout<<""<<endl;
            }else{

            }
    }
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Would you like to re print the results?"<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Hit 1 for yes, and 0 for no"<<endl;
    cin>>ifstatement;
    if(ifstatement == 1){
            flag = true;
    }else{
            flag = false;
    }
    if(flag == true){
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Print Preorder"<<endl;
    genesistree.printpreorder();
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Print in order"<<endl;
    genesistree.printinorder();
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Print Postorder"<<endl;
    genesistree.printpostorder();
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    }else{
            if(flag == false){
            cout<<""<<endl;
            }
    }
    cout<<""<<endl;

cout<<"Enter the ammount of datavalues you would like to add"<<endl;
    cin>>addvalues;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    if(addvalues > 0){
    for(c = deletevalues, c >= 0; c--;){
            cout<<"Enter a datavalue to add in the tree"<<endl;
            cin>>newnewdata;
            genesistree.insertdata(newnewdata);
            cout<<""<<endl;

    }
    }else{
            if(deletevalues == 0){
                    cout<<""<<endl;
            }else{

            }
    }
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Would you like to re print the results?"<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Hit 1 for yes, and 0 for no"<<endl;
    cin>>ifstatement;
    if(ifstatement == 1){
            flag = true;
    }else{
            flag = false;
    }
    if(flag == true){
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Print Preorder"<<endl;
    genesistree.printpreorder();
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Print in order"<<endl;
    genesistree.printinorder();
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Print Postorder"<<endl;
    genesistree.printpostorder();
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    }else{
            if(flag == false){
            cout<<""<<endl;
            }
    }
    */
    cout<<""<<endl;
    countNodes(genesistree);
            /*
    btree<int> mytree;
    string QandA[7];
    int Tpos[7];
    QandA[0] = "Question 1";
    QandA[1] = "Question 2";//Y to 0
    QandA[2] = "Question 3";//N to 0
    QandA[3] = "answer 1";//Y to 1
    QandA[4] = "answer 2";//N to 1
    QandA[5] = "answer 3";//N to 2
    QandA[6] = "answer ";//Y to 2

    Tpos[0] = 50;
    Tpos[1] = 40;
    Tpos[2] = 60;
    Tpos[3] = 20;
    Tpos[4] = 45;
    Tpos[5] = 70;
    Tpos[6] = 55;

    for(int i = 0; i<=6; i++){

            mytree.insertdata2(Tpos[i],QandA[i]);

    }
    mytree.yesno();



    cout<<endl;    
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you keep track of the number of nodes while creating the tree?

Comment: Holy giant code dump, Batman!

Answer (score 1):

Your `countNodes` method takes a `treeNode` pointer. It doesn't look like there is any way to access your root node, so that method is useless outside the `btree` class.

I would make another method like so

```
template<class datatype>
int btree<datatype>::getNodeCount() const 
{
    if ( root == NULL ) return 0;
    // Otherwise continue counting from root.
    ...
```

Comment: Why does it seem to me that counting nodes this way is stupid? Am i missing something? The point of binary tree is speed and it is doing a linear counting? really?

Comment: The question is _how do I call my countNodes method_, I intentionally haven't made any comments on the efficiency of how it's implemented. And who's to say re-assessing tree size every time a new individual element or new tree is added/removed is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of solving this:

In the class, a new function:

```
template<class datatype>
class btree{
public:
  ...
  int countNodes();
  int countNodes(treenode<datatype> *p);
};
```

int countNodes(), to be called from your program.

```
template<class datatype>
int btree<datatype>::countNodes(){
  return countNodes(root);
}
```

int countNodes(treenode *p), to be called internally (probably should be private, since clients don't have access to the root node anyways):

```
template<class datatype>
int btree<datatype>::countNodes(treenode<datatype> *p){
  int count = 1;    
  if ( p == NULL ){
    return 0;  
  }else{
    count += countNodes(p->lchild);  
    count += countNodes(p->rchild);
  }
  return count;  
}
```

Note that the implementation for countNodes(treenode *p) has also changed.

Then in main:

```
btree<int> genesistree;
genesistree.insertdata(14);
genesistree.insertdata(2);
genesistree.insertdata(34);
genesistree.insertdata(41);
genesistree.insertdata(12);
cout << genesistree.countNodes();
```

Prints 5, the size of the tree.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, and I apologize for my late response.  I assume to count from either side of the tree I would either just use the same block of code only including only count += countNodes(p->lchild) or would it be something slightly different such as inheriting countnodes but instead of from root but from the first child of root? And the second fix worked beautifully.

Comment: Your code had a bug in it. The code I posted corrected it. It was a redefinition of int count. Make sure you compare the code I posted  for countNodes(treenode *p) with yours to see what changed.

Comment: Managed to get the rest to work. Thank you very much, that break through was enough to skyrocket through the rest.